# Raspberry Pi not detecting MPU6050 with i2cdetect

Tags: raspbian, sensor, i2c, pi-zero-w, mpu6050

I am trying to connect my GY-521 MPU6050 to my Raspberry Pi Zero W using I2C detect but I'm unable to find the MPU6050 on the table.

The results using i2cdetect:

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --`

I have been following this tutorial: https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/measuring-rotation-and-acceleration-raspberry-pi/

I have followed the tutorial up until the point where the sensor is detected using I2C.

I have looked through forums to try and solve this, but the results I found were not able to fix this.

The connections I have are in the photos below:
[image: MPU6050]

[image: Raspberry Pi Zero W]

If there is any further detail required, please let me know. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to use `sudo` with `i2cdetect`.

The most likely problem is not connecting `ADO` to either ground or 3V3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have connected the ADO pin on the MPU6050 to the ground (9th GPIO pin) and I also tried connecting the VCC on the MPU6050 to the 5v Power on the Raspberry Pi with the ADO connected to the 3.3v and still not gotten the results on the table. Any reason why this may be happening?